# Encontrar y eliminar archivos con menos de n número de días

Tags: linux, consola, unix, búsquedas, zsh

Necesito eliminar los archivos **jpg** de dentro de un árbol de directorios, pero sólo necesito eliminar los archivos que tienen menos de **n** días de haber sido creados. E.g. Eliminar las imágenes jpg que tengan 3 días o menos de haber sido creadas.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento pero no funciona:

```
$ find ~/la/ruta -name *.jpg -mtime -2 -exec rm {} \;
zsh: no matches found: *.jpg

$ find la/ruta/*.jpg -mtime -2 -exec rm {} \; 
zsh: no matches found: la/ruta/*.jpg
```

Comment: El primer comando al menos, es correcto, simplemente pareciera que no ha encontrado archivos `*.jpg`, por que dices que no funciona? Ten en cuenta que `-mtime - 2` significa archivos modificados en las últimas 48 horas, y por otro lado la fecha de creación es un dato que no esta disponible en todos los sistemas de archivo de Linux, te diría que en la mayoría no lo tienes.

Comment: Aparentemente el error lo arroja `zsh` y no `find`... qué pasa si pruebas con ``'*.jpg'``.

Comment: Tal y como comenta @archimiro el problema parece estar en el uso de `*` sin entrecomillar. Esto provoca que se intente expandir y no dé con ningún resultado. Creo que es un comportamiento diferente al de Bash en estos casos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He realizado la instalacion de `zsh`, y al tratar de reproducir tu problema, efectivamente, arroja el mismo error.

> zsh: no matches found: *.jpg

Generalmente, cuando se usa el parametro `-name` o `-iname` en el comando `find`, suelen usarse las comillas, seasen simples o dobles. Dejando el comando de esta manera:

```
find /ruta/carpeta/ -name "*.jpg" -mtime -2 -exec rm {} \;
```

Puedes tambien usar `-iname`, en caso que alguno de los archivos tenga como extension `.JPG`. Ya que `-iname` ignora si son mayusculas o minusculas.

---

Respecto a la **fecha de creacion**, podriamos mirar un ejemplo:

**1)** Creamos un fichero.

```
touch archivo.txt
```

**2)** Miremos la fecha.

```
ls -lh
```

Obtenemos este resultado:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 **Jul 12 08:33** archivo.txt

**3)** Agregamos algo de informacion al fichero.

```
echo "Hola mundo" > archivo.txt
```

**4)** Miremos la fecha nuevamente.

```
ls -lh
```

Obtenemos este resultado:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11 **Jul 12 08:34** archivo.txt

La **fecha de creacion**, no es un dato al que se pueda tener acceso de acuerdo al estandar **POSIX**, ya que este define **3 fechas** para un archivo, de acuerdo a esta [documentacion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html).

Y en esta [pregunta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file) de Stack Exchange, cito:

> The POSIX standard only defines three distinct timestamps to be stored for each file: the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed.

Cuya **idea principal** en Español, quiere decir:

> El estandar de POSIX define tres fechas para guardar en cada archivo, la fecha de ultimo acceso, la fecha de ultima modificacion y la fecha en la que el archivo cambio por ultima vez.

***Lo que nos da a entender que si el archivo es modificado, sera muy complicado buscarlo y borrarlo por fecha de creacion.***

---

### Conclusion

Para **borrar** los ficheros con menos de **N dias**, bastaria hacer los siguiente:

```
find /ruta/directorio/ -iname "*.jpg" -type f -mtime -N -exec rm {} \;
```

Basta reemplazar la **N** por el numero de dias.

Mas si lo que deseas es solo borrar directorios:

```
find /ruta/directorio/ -iname "*.jpg" -type d -mtime -N -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Sería bueno explicar por qué se usan comillas (expansión de variables y todo eso). Y añadir tildes :)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: @fedorqui una pregunta ¿Esto funcionaría igual para eliminar directorios? Sólo quitando la parte de **-iname.....** y cambiar a **rm -rf {} \; **

Comment: @akko: debería.

Comment: @akko Respecto al comentario he agregado una pequeña actualizacion aclarando lo del borrado de directorios o de ficheros

Comment: @fedorqui  ups! Tienes razon! Lo corregiré en un rato, he dejado mal el comando

Comment: Muy completa Iván, +1