# Eliminar archivos con mas de x días en mi servidor

Tags: cpanel

tengo una duda con respecto a eliminar archivos de mi servidor, he visto [esta entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86232/encontrar-y-eliminar-archivos-con-menos-de-n-n%C3%BAmero-de-d%C3%ADas) y creo que el cronjob para CPanel me puede funcionar, pero tengo mis dudas

```
0 4 * * * find /sub.dominio.com.sv/uploads/files01/*.* -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

El punto es que creo que este código solo me borra archivos de la carpeta **Files01**, y a veces me toca crear mas carpetas dendro de "**uploads**" que tambien quiero que se borren sus archivos despues de 30 días de subidos"

Ahora, me servirá eliminar la carpeta "**files01**" del cronjob para que me escanee todos los archivos de la carpeta "**uploads**" y todas sus subcarpetas?

Gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

**Edito:**
Al final me funcionó el siguiente cronjob:

```
find /home/web/sub.dominio.com.sv/uploads/* -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

De esta forma se borran todos los archivos contenidos en uploads y subcarpetas, sin borrar a estas últimas.

Mis agradecimientos a Claudio Lepin por haberme orientado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien encaminado. Si quieres eliminar todos los archivos dentro de alguna carpeta dentro de uploads, pues puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

`4 * * * find /sub.dominio.com.sv/uploads/*/*.* -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

Ese comando borra todos los archivos contenidos en todas las carpetas dentro de uploads. Si de antemano sabes que tus nombres siempre serán filesXX, puedes asegurarte de sólo eliminar los contenidos de esos directorios:

`4 * * * find /sub.dominio.com.sv/uploads/files*/*.* -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la idea es borrar los archivos de todas las carpetas, no asi las carpetas, ya que contienen el nombre de cada usuario, y pues, la idea es no modificar el cronjob cada vez que agregue una carpeta.

Comment: Sí, con ese comando sólo borrarás los archivos dentro de las carpeta, no las carpetas.

Comment: Gracias amigo, la implementaré y sigún el resultado regreso a marcar tu respuesta, gracias por todo.